# How to use jquery on iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I have button within iframe that needs to clicked after the page is loaded. How to do it? I have tried using Jquery but trigger event but something is missing.

```
jQuery(document).find('iframe').each(function() {
    var sel = jQuery(this).attr('__idm_frm__');
    find('cbe_searchcontainer a').click();
});
```

Comment: What is the `find()` function on the second line? You're not calling the jQuery find method at that point, though perhaps that's what you *want* to do?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('iframe').contents().find('#cbe_searchcontainer a').each(function() {
  $(this).trigger("click");
})
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If cbe_searchcontainer is ID, may be you should change it to #cbe_searchcontainer to make a correct jQuery selection.